# Is it possible to diagonalize a Hamiltonian with both quadratic and linear terms in the fermi operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information, majorana-fermions, spin-chains

A quadratic Hamiltonian in the fermi operators is exactly diagonalizable. The most convenient way of describing these Hamiltonians is of the form:

$$\mathcal{H}=\displaystyle \sum_{j,k}(\alpha_{jk}a_{j}^{\dagger}a_{k}-\alpha_{jk}^{*}a_{j}a_{k}^{\dagger}+\beta_{jk}a_{j}a_{k}-\beta_{jk}^{*}a_{j}^{\dagger}a_{k}^{\dagger})$$

However, for the Hamiltonian I am considering, apart from these terms I am also left with a linear term like $(a_2+a_2^{\dagger})$ [If you want to know where it comes from: I get it from the Jordan-Wigner transformation of a boundary term in the so called [cluster hamiltonian]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_state).

So, my question is: it is possible to exactly diagonalize such a Hamiltonian with both quadratic and linear terms in the fermi operators?

Comment: You can of course still use exact diagonalization (as in the numerical technique). Are you rather asking about whether it's possible to analytically diagonalize the problem using e.g. a procedure akin to the usual Bogoliubov transformation?

Comment: @Anyon yes, I am looking for something that would give me an analytical solution.

Comment: Yes, the procedure is performed in this reference: https://doi.org/10.1143/PTP.57.1554